# Solving for roots of zero

Tags: optimization, roots

Given the equation $$\ln(1-e^{-\frac{km}n})+\frac{kme^{-\frac{km}n}}{n(1-e^{\frac{-km}n})}=0$$
I am trying to look for the value of $k$. $k$ should actually be $\frac{m}n\ln 2$. However. I am unsure of how to get to that.

Here's what I've tried:
$$\ln\left(1-e^{-\frac{km}n}\right)=-\frac{kme^{-\frac{km}n}}{n\left(1-e^{\frac{-km}n}\right)}$$
$$1-e^{-\frac{km}n}=e^{\left(-\frac{kme^{-\frac{km}n}}{n\left(1-e^{\frac{-km}n}\right)}\right)}$$
$$e^{-\frac{km}n}=1-e^{\left(-\frac{kme^{-\frac{km}n}}{n\left(1-e^{\frac{-km}n}\right)}\right)}$$
$${-\frac{km}n}=\ln\left(1-e^{\left(-\frac{kme^{-\frac{km}n}}{n(1-e^{\frac{-km}n})}\right)}\right)$$
$$\implies k=-\frac{n}m\;\ln\left(1-e^{\left(-\frac{kme^{-\frac{km}n}}{n\left(1-e^{\frac{-km}n}\right)}\right)}\right)\\$$

and I am stuck. Can anyone please help me with this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Let $e^{\frac{-km}{n}} = u, u>0, u \neq 1 \implies \frac{km}{n} = -\ln(u)$

Given equation becomes: $\ln(1-u)+ \dfrac{-u\ln(u)}{1-u} =0$

Multiply by $1-u$ to get: $(1-u)ln(1-u)- u\ln(u) =0 \implies ln((1-u)^{1-u}) = ln(u^u)$

$\implies (1-u)^{1-u} = u^u \implies 1-u = u \implies u = \frac{1}{2}$ $$\implies e^{\frac{-km}{n}} = \frac{1}{2} \implies k = \frac{n}{m}\ln(2).$$

More rigorous solution of why this is the only solution can be done using calculus.